# Is there URL class in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, url

In JavaScript, is there any class equivalent for

- NSURL class in iOS SDK or
- URL class in Java?

With such class, I want to:

- normalize URL,
- compose a URL from scheme, host, path components, etc..., and
- decompose a URL into its elements.

Comment: Part of your question can be answered with https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location

Comment: @sachleen Thanks! I didn't know how the Location class works!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

James Padolsey had tackled this problem.

In a nutshell, you can create an anchor element using `document.createElement()`, and several of its native properties are then easily accessible, such as `protocol`, `port`, and `hostname`.

For more information: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/parsing-urls-with-the-dom/

Comment: That is beautiful! I'd vote twice if it's possible. Using the `<a>` tag to parse url via href is brilliant!

Comment: Yup, that was my reaction too, when I read that blog entry. It was literally under our noses the entire time.

Comment: BEAUTIFULL. And I never use all caps.

Answer (score 5):

Yes! There is now a standard, broadly compatible, [URL class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) for Javascript.

> The constructor takes a url parameter, and an optional base parameter to use as a base if the url parameter is a relative URL

```
const url = new URL(window.location.href);
console.log(url.hostname); // "www.example.com"
console.log(url.pathname); // "/cats"
```