# Regular expression to retrieve from the URL

Tags: javascript, regex

**/test-test-test/test.aspx**

Hi there,

I am having a bit difficult to retrieve the first bit out from the the above URL.

**test-test-test**

I tried this `/[\w+|-]/g` but it match the last test.aspx as well.

Please help out.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a positive lookahead assertion. `|` inside a character class would match a literal `|` symbol. It won't act like an alternation operator. So i suggest you to remove that.

```
[\w-]+(?=\/)
```

`(?=\/)` called positive lookahead assertion which asserts that the match must be followed by an forward slash. In our case `test-test-test` only followed by a forward slash, so it got matched. `[\w-]+` matches one or more word character or hyphen. `+` repeats the previous token one or more times.

Example:

```
> "/test-test-test/test.aspx".match(/[\w-]+(?=\/)/g)
[ 'test-test-test' ]
```

Comment: (?=\/) What's this means? Cheers

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing it is using the Dom Parser as stated here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13465791/970247. 
Then you could access to the segments of the url using for example: `myURL.segments; // = Array = ['test-test-test', 'test.aspx']`

Comment: this way is smart, i just want to have a good at regular Expression :)

Comment: If it's for a really specific need a regex is probably easier to implement indeed.

Answer (score 0):

- `[\w+|-]` is wrong, should be `[\w-]+`. "A series of characters that are either word characters or hyphens", not "a single character that is a word character, a plus, a pipe, or a hyphen".
- The `g` flag means global match, so naturally all matches will be found instead of just the first one. So you should remove that.

  ```
  > '/test-test-test/test.aspx'.match(/[\w-]+/)
  < ["test-test-test"]
  ```