# determine if string/url belongs to particular domain

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to use a `RegExp` in `JavaScript` to determine if the current string (which represents a URL) belongs to the `github.com` domain.

Example, if `http://developer.github.com` or `http://subdomain.github.com` return `true`, otherwise return `false`.

Tried using a wildcard in place of the subdomain to allow for any number of any characters between `http://` and `.github.com` .. `/http://[a-z]*.github.com/ig`

http://jsfiddle.net/bobbyrne01/nrp6pkkq/1/

`js` ..

```
var str0 = 'http://exämple.org/foo.html?baz=la#bumm';
var str1 = 'https://developer.github.com/v3/';
var str2 = 'http://developer.github.com/v3/';
var str3 = 'http://test.github.com/v3/';
var str4 = 'http://example.org';

var patt = new RegExp("/http://[a-z]*.github.com/ig");
document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = patt.test(str0) + '<br/>';
document.getElementById('results').innerHTML += patt.test(str1) + '<br/>';
document.getElementById('results').innerHTML += patt.test(str2) + '<br/>';
document.getElementById('results').innerHTML += patt.test(str3) + '<br/>';
document.getElementById('results').innerHTML += patt.test(str4) + '<br/>';
```

`html` ..

```
<div id="results"></div>
```

`output` ..

```
false
false
false
false
false
```

Expected output:

```
false
false
true
true
false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `RegExp` constructor with double quotes as delimiter, then you don't need another delimiter ie, `/`

```
var patt = new RegExp("http://[a-z]*\\.github\\.com", "ig");
```

Example:

```
> var patt = new RegExp("http://[a-z]*\\.github\\.com", "ig");
> var str0 = 'http://exämple.org/foo.html?baz=la#bumm';
undefined
> patt.test(str0)
false
> var str1 = 'https://developer.github.com/v3/';
> patt.test(str1)
false
> var str2 = 'http://developer.github.com/v3/';
> patt.test(str2)
true
```

Answer (score 2):

I really suggest you use the Dom parser instead of Regex to parse an URL. Using this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13465791/970247. You'll be able to retrieve the domain like this:

```
var myURL = parseURL('https://developer.github.com/v3/');
myURL.host;     // = 'developer.github.com'
```

Comment: DOM (Document Object Model) is relative to XML-like languages. It is not relative to urls syntax.

Comment: Yes you're right, it's a bit misleading. Do you have any suggestion ? The DOM api ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this pattern with the [`RegExp.prototype.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) method:

```
function isDomain(domain, url) {
    var pat = '^https?://(?:[^/@:]*:[^/@]*@)?(?:[^/:]+\.)?' + domain + '(?=[/:]|$)';
    var re = new RegExp(pat, 'i');
    return re.test(url);
}

var url = 'http://test.github.com/v3/';

console.log(isDomain('github.com', url));
```

or you can implement it as a `String` method:

```
String.prototype.isDomain = function (domain) {
    var pat = '^https?://(?:[^/@:]*:[^/@]*@)?(?:[^/:]+\.)?' + domain + '(?=[/:]|$)';
    var re = new RegExp(pat, 'i');
    return re.test(this);
}

console.log(url.isDomain('github.com'));
```

pattern details:

```
^ # anchor for the start of the string

https?://  # scheme (note that you can improve it addying ftp, sftp...)

(?:[^/@:]*:[^/@]*@)?  # optional login/password

(?:[^/:]+\.)?         # optional subdomain

github\.com           # the domain

(?=[/:]|$)            # check if the domain is followed by:
                      #   - a path /
                      #   - a port :80
                      #   - the end of the string $
                      # to prevent false positives
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//example:
//verifyDomain('http://test.github.com/v3/','github.com')
const verifyDomain = (url, domain) => {
    domain = formatDomain(domain).split('.') // array [github,com]
    url = formatDomain(url).split('.') // array [test,github,com]
    while (url.length > domain.length) url.shift() // transform url array in [github,com]
    if (domain.toString() === url.toString()) return true
    return false
}

const formatDomain = (domain) => {
    // if https://www.stackoverflow.com/page/... return stackoverflow.com
    return (domain.indexOf('://') > -1 ? domain.split('/')[2] : domain.split('/')[0]).replace('www.', '')
}
```

this worked for me